# onclick funtion is not working in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom-events, onclicklistener

*Node.js stop working of javascript code*

**my File structure**

> app.js
>
> index.html
>
> index.js

### But if I run it without node it's work and alert come's

**app.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=80; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) throw err;    
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
console.log(request.addListener.name);
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
    console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1/`);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="start()">onclick</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function start(){
alert('start');
}
```

anyone, please suggest me the solution how can I call Javascript function when running on node by clicking the button or change in input data.

Comment: u have to create static server, and server static file. Check network, you can't able to load index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example is given below. I will recommend use `third-party` libraries like [express-js](https://expressjs.com/) to create the server.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = 8080;
http
  .createServer(({ url }, response) => {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    if (url == "/") fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
    else {
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, url);
      const stats = fs.existsSync(filePath);
      if (stats) fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response);
    }
  })
  .listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server only serve `index.html`
If you look in **Network Tab** (In the code inspector) the index.js request fail
You need to send your index.js file when it's require.
If you just use Nodejs for this. I think the best is to use [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/fr/) it's really easy.